# Save facebook friends?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am working on rails 3 and using the koala gem to get a connection to the facebook graph api. 
And I am using omniauth to autenticate users.

So when a new user logs to the site, the session_controller handles the new user:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
def create
  user = User.from_omniauth(env['omniauth.auth'])
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "Signed in!"
end
```

The create method call the "from_omniauth" class metod in the User.rb model, to create a new user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :friends

    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
     where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
     user.provider = auth["provider"]
     user.uid = auth["uid"]
     user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
     user.first_name = auth["info"]["first_name"]
     user.last_name = auth["info"]["last_name"]
     user.image = auth["info"]["image"]
     user.email = auth["info"]["email"]
     user.gender = auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["gender"]
     user.location = auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["location"]["name"]          
     user.token = auth["credentials"]["token"]
    end
     user.save!
    end
```

I would like to save user facebook friends also and store it in a separate tabel called friends, so I made this friend model:

```
class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true

  def facebook
    @Facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(token)
  end

  def add_friends
    facebook { |fb| fb.get_connection("me", "friends") }
  end
end
```

But I am lost on how to store users friends, I whould like to know:

- How I can create a user, and store it friends
- Where should I call the add_friends method?
- fb.get_connection("me", "friends") return a array of hashes, like this `> [{"name"=>"Johan Gyllenspetz", "id"=>"3624556"}, {"name"=>"Gustaf Josefsson",` . And I would like to store the name and uid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I'd do this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friends

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    user = where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth["provider"]
      user.uid = auth["uid"]
      user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
      user.first_name = auth["info"]["first_name"]
      user.last_name = auth["info"]["last_name"]
      user.image = auth["info"]["image"]
      user.email = auth["info"]["email"]
      user.gender = auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["gender"]
      user.location = auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["location"]["name"]          
      user.token = auth["credentials"]["token"]
    end
    user.add_friends
    user.save
    user
  end

  def add_friends
    @facebook.get_connection("me", "friends").each do |hash|
      self.friends.where(:name => hash['name'], :uid => hash['id']).first_or_create
    end
  end

  private

  def facebook
    @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(token)
  end

end
```

Comment: I get this error: undefined method `add_friends' for #<User:0x007fcfcb30e218>

Comment: @Veraticus: In the code that you posted, the add_friends method is inside the class method so it ends up beging a class method to, rather then an instance method. So I have removed the facebook and add_friends method from their and it will work. And one should call the facebook method rather than accessing the instance variable directly. cheers!

Comment: @SHUMAcupcake : so where did you put a method excatly, and how you call for those method? i having a same problem here.